# How can I delete returned object in the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

class JMP
{
    public:
        std::string number;
        JMP() {}
        JMP(const char* num) { number = num; }
        JMP operator+(const JMP &j)
        {
            // Allocate object
            JMP *sum_obj = new JMP("0");
            sum_obj->number[0] += 1;
            return *sum_obj;
        } // <--- memory leak
};

int main()
{
    JMP *a = new JMP(), *b = new JMP(), *c = new JMP();
    *c = *a + *b;
    delete a; delete b; delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

How I can delete the allocated `sum_obj` object?

Can using smart pointers help here?

Notice: I am doing this object for heavy math calculations, please don't suggest using stack memory.

Any reference or helpful answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot, one the `operator+` exits the pointer to the object has been lost. Instead you should not allocate it in the first place. `JMP operator+(JMP &j) { return JMP("0"); }` does the same as your code without the unnecessary allocation.

Comment: Don't do this. `JMP *sum_obj = new JMP("0"); return *sum_obj;` can be replaced with `return  JMP("0");`

Comment: If you use a smart pointer(for example `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`), it will handle the deletion automatically for you

Comment: Sometimes developers who know other languages, don't appreciate that in C++ you don't have to use `new` for everything, and that it's perfectly acceptable to copy objects not pointers.

Comment: This object is a heavy object for heavy math calculations and it is not logical for me to use the stack memory, friends

Comment: @JibelSadeghi Then use a smart pointer, as already suggested. But in any case `return JMP("0");` does not copy anything. You might want to check out return value optimization (RVO).

Comment: but you're already making a with your current code and have 3 objects on the stack.

Comment: @john Thank you, but can you tell me exactly how I should use the smart pointer in such a code so that it automatically deletes itself?

Comment: You cannot switch to a smart pointer in that code (I mean `operator+`). You have to change all your code so that is uses smart pointers instead of `JMP`. e,g, `std::shared_ptr<JMP>`. Or change `JMP` so that internally it uses smart pointers and is therefore cheap to copy.

Comment: *it is not logical for me to use the stack memory*  In your `main` routine, you have JMP a, b and c which are all stack memory.

Comment: There's no quick fix here, for your `operator+` to return a reference is fundamentally flawed. You have to make a decision, use values, with the copying that involves (although RVO and move semantics means that should be less than you anticipate) or switch entirely smart pointers and all that entails.

Comment: @john I wrote a very simple and short code for this so that if someone like you has an idea from scratch, he can implement it. If you can, please provide your suggestion for using smart pointers in the answer section.

Comment: @JibelSadeghi Now, after your edit, you will remove `sum_obj`, but you will always leak `c`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen How to escape the `c` leak?

Comment: @JibelSadeghi Sorry but the question is now closed. But smart pointers are not hard. Just forget about using pointers and references and replace `JMP*` or `JMP&` with `std::shared_ptr<JMP>`, replace `new JMP(...)` with `std::make_shared<JMP>(...)`. That's more or less all you need to do.

Comment: Also, the `std::string` is itself a kind of smart pointer, specialized for string operations, which is heap allocated.  (There's a short string optimization, which your std::string may or may not have.  But that's irrelevant for longer strings.)

Comment: Its ok to worry about performance, but adding `new` and raw pointers will not make your code magically run faster, but certainly it will introduce bugs.

Comment: An `operator+()` normally returns an object by VALUE, not by reference.   You wouldn't expect `c = a + b` to cause a memory leak, regardless of the types of `a`, `b`, and `c`.   One possible definition would be `JMP operator+(const JMP &rhs) const {JMP retval("0"); retval.number[0] += 1; return retval;}`   Also, in your code, `delete a,b,c;` is incorrect and (presumably, assuming you want `a`, `b,` and `c` to all be deleted) should be `delete a; delete b; delete c`.

Comment: C++ was the first language to introduce the `new` keyword, but it is also the language that uses the keyword very differently than others. A good design should ideally not involve any appearence of this keyword in user code; Unless some very complicated, higly hand-optimized data-structure is involved; very unlikely in majority of applications. Reputable Libraries use it on behalf of user code, but the implementors know exactly what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, returning a reference is wrong. You need to return a value.

Secondly, the obvious solution is to not use dynamic memory at all, e.g.:

```
class JMP
{
    public:
        std::string number;
        JMP() {}
        JMP(const char* num) { number = num; }
        JMP operator+(const JMP &j)
        {
            JMP sum_obj("0");
            sum_obj.number[0] += 1;
            return sum_obj;
        }
};
```

Though, if you really need to do calculation with a heap object, you can do it like this:

```
#include <memory>

class JMP
{
    public:
        std::string number;
        JMP() {}
        JMP(const char* num) { number = num; }
        JMP operator+(const JMP &j)
        {
            // Allocate object
            auto sum_obj = std::make_unique<JMP>("0");
            sum_obj->number[0] += 1;
            return *sum_obj; // returns a copy
        }
};
```

Note that the heap solution is more costly. Both becauase using dynamic memory has a cost in itself, but also since it prevents return-value-optimization.

Edit: In the unique_ptr solution, it actually turns the copy into a move if changing the return line to: `return std::move(*sum_obj);`:

See working code, and difference depending on which return line that is commented out: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/adhcnd7xW)

Comment: Does the second code delete the `sum_obj` after returning it to the heap memory?

Comment: Yes Jibel, that is the point of it being a unique_ptr. It deletes its content when going out of scope, i.e. at the end of the `operator+` function.

Comment: It is rarely necessary to dynamically create an object, just to return a copy of that object, and then release the dynamically allocated object.   More often than not, a requirement to do that is a sign that some aspect of the class design is badly broken - and the better approach is to fix the design, not work around it with dynamic allocation, copy, and release.

Comment: @Jibel This code is correct (I think) but it does copy the `JMP` object when it returns from `operator+`, which I believe was what you were trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, can i avoid from copying with `std::move()` in this code?

Comment: @Jibel Yes, you turn the copy into a move instead, see the link I edited into the answer.